# How to add into ArrayList<String>, time recorded by service log

Tags: java

```java
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
///////////////
///////////////
}
```

This is some Java code with `doGet` response, request; I know how to print out path and host, however, I can't print out the time of access.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase. So `List` should really be `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, time of access is.. right now. `ZonedDateTime.now()` would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the current time (= “time of access”) by creating a new `java.util.Date` object:

```
List.add(new java.util.Date().toString());
```

— Though it would be more conventional to let a [logging library](https://www.baeldung.com/java-logging-intro) take care of this for you.

Comment: Why not use java.time package?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Because it doesn’t matter — the real solution would use a logging library, which provides timestamps automatically anyway.